# amCharts: Set value 0 if no data is available on that date

Tags: amcharts

How can I set value is zero if that date data doesn't exist? Do I have to do it in PHP? Or can it be easily done using AmCharts?

[image: Value is not zero]

Answer (score 2):

You can directly do it from AMCharts.

```
var chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
chart.connect= false;
```

this line will avoid joining points if the value is missing. Defalut is true.

Comment: Connect would remove the whole line, it does not connect at zero where no data is available.

Answer (score 0):

I use graph.connect;

http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#connect

but if period is not one,example(15min,15second) ,u must also set minPeriod.
http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#minPeriod

example:jsfiddle.net/fruwei/fwazw2fx/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference. And please answer in English.